# How do I format date literals in dynamic linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dynamic

I am using dynamic Linq to return data for user-input search criteria.  My query is working fine except for the user selected dates.  My current code is:

```
        StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();

        if (startDate.HasValue || endDate.HasValue)
        {
            DateTime searchStartDate = startDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTime searchEndDate = endDate.HasValue ? endDate.Value : DateTime.MaxValue;

            whereClause.AppendFormat("Date >= {0} && Date <= {1}",
                searchStartDate.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
                searchEndDate.Date.ToUniversalTime());
        }

        if (whereClause.Length > 0)
        {
            return (from p in this.repository.GetQueryable<Party>() select p)
                .Where(whereClause.ToString())
                .ToList();
        }
```

The query falls over because the comparison is being done between a DateTime field and a Int32 field, meaning the query has interpreted my date literals as integers.

How should I be formatting the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you parsing strings in a LINQ expression?  The entire point of LINQ is to avoid that.

```
var q =  from p in this.repository.GetQueryable<Party>() select p;

if (startDate.HasValue || endDate.HasValue) 
{ 
  var searchStartDate = startDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue; 
  var searchEndDate = endDate.HasValue ? endDate.Value : DateTime.MaxValue; 
  return 
         q.Where (p=> p.Date >= searchStartDate.ToUniversalTime() 
                   && p.Date <= searchEndDate.ToUniversalTime()).ToList();
} 
return q.ToList();
```

UPDATE:
In response to comments: I'm building that one at run-time.  The question isn't run-time vs compile-time; it's "in strings" vs "in code".   StringBuilder lets you append text; LINQ lets to chain lamdbas.  It all works out the same --- except your code is type-safe and syntax checked using lambdas.

To demostrate this concept further, the following code compiles & runs fine, and allows to you to change the Where clause based on the values of `oddsOnly` and `lowerLimit`.

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

bool oddsOnly = true; 
bool lowerLimit = 5;

var q = from i in nums select i;

if (oddsOnly)
    q = q.Where( n=> n%2 == 1);

if (lowerLimit != 0)
    q = q.Where( n=> n >= lowerLimit);

foreach(var i in q)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Depending on how you set those values, it will use zero, one or both of the where clauses.

Comment: In normal this statement is o.k. however in some cases, e.g. dynamic generation of the filter from the user inputs, Dynamic Linq is a valid alernative.

Comment: James, I need to build up the query at run-time because the user can enter any or none of the various search terms.  I left out the other terms in my code snippet but the .Where string that I'm building can only be done at run-time.

Comment: The problem is I have none or any number of terms in my .Where clause depending on what the user enters.  I left out the non-date snippets but for each piece of user input I check for nulls and append the relevant terms to the whereClause string only if needed.  My whereClause may be empty at the end.  I don't want to perform the search within the "if not null..." sections because I'd end up with multiple "if...else" branches depending on which search terms were being used.  Isn't there a way of building the whole clause as a string and then executing it at the end?

Comment: See my new addition to the answer.  I believe that addresses your concerns.

Comment: James, this works perfectly and is, as you say, better than parsing strings as I was doing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: the question was about "dynamic linq"

Comment: @MVision- The question was about achieving a result.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
.Where("Date >= @0 && Date <= @1",
                searchStartDate.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
                searchEndDate.Date.ToUniversalTime())
```

instead.

**In reply to Val's comment:**

OK, then you can do:

```
whereClause.AppendFormat("Date.ToString() >= \"{0}\" && Date.ToString() <= \"{1}\"",
                searchStartDate.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
                searchEndDate.Date.ToUniversalTime());
```

You have to convert the Date in the query to a string and then compare it a quoted string literal. Without the quotes the parser is inerpreting the numbers inserted into the where clause as integers - what should explain the error you originally got.

Comment: Obalix, I really need the entire .Where clause to be a string because I am appending other search terms, so the date element to the clause may not be there.

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamic LINQ string would need to look something like:

```
"Date >= DateTime(2015, 10, 21)"
```

This is mentioned in the documentation in the DynamicQuery project in the download mentioned at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.

Note, there isn't a `new` before the `DateTime` constructor.

I tried this and it works. I'm using Telerik's RadGrid control for ASP.NET AJAX. The grid builds the filter string and I needed to add the filter to my query to get the filter to execute in the database using LINQ to Entities. The problem is that the generated filter needed to be altered a little for it to work with LINQ to Entities as opposed to LINQ to Objects. It was doing a `DateTime.Parse()` which isn't supported in LINQ to Entities.