# Is it possible to perform a linq query with string concatenation instead of identifiers?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I have a query which works fine

`var queryItems = rawQuery.ObsDataResultList.AsQueryable().Where("Name = @0 AND AuthoredDate = @1" +, selectedItem, dateKey).ToList();`

I want to update the query to

`var queryItems = rawQuery.ObsDataResultList.AsQueryable().Where("Name = @0 AND AuthoredDate = " + dateKey.ToString(), selectedItem).ToList();`

Note the only thing I changed was removing the identifier.  Now, I receive Error

> Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32'

How can I fix the error without reverting back to the original query?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?! Why would you want to deliberately ruin a pefectly good query?

Comment: @MarkByers - I plan to take a list of such where statements and store them off as constants in a struct. The struct could be a single point of reference for supported queries.  With the parameters in the list it's difficult to do so as the # of parameters could vary widely.  Is there some technical advantage to the first form?  E.G. something akin to parameterizing params to avoid injection?

Comment: @PBrianMackey: Yes, you could get injection. Why is it difficult to store a list of parameters?

Comment: You may be able to avoid using Dynamic LINQ altogether. See the accepted answer to this question for how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288296/how-do-i-format-date-literals-in-dynamic-linq

Comment: I see that with every question, you want to extend what you can do with linq query. If you have so dynamic conditions, why don't you just use the classical DB connections and pure SQL.

Comment: @l.b because these queries are going to be formed at runtime by the business users.  Accrding to ScottGu's blog thats a use case for dynamic linq

Comment: @MarkByers - a collection is a great suggestion.  Ty

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey `because these queries are going to be formed at runtime by the business users`, So before `Linq` no one could write such applications? "*if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing quotes:

```
.Where("Name = @0 AND AuthoredDate = \"" + dateKey + "\"")
```

It seems like a really bad idea to spoil your code like this though. Your original query seems much better.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep this in mind and certainly attempt to derive a solution based off the original form.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I originally assumed single quotes would be needed, but after Googling I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2288328/61974) uses double-quotes so I changed my answer.